# Laravel 5.2 call of non-static Query Builder methods like static methods

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

I am digging deep into Laravel 5.2 architecture. I noticed one thing that there is no static method of some functions, like insert, update in the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class yet we access it like `User::insert()`

There is another function `performInsert()` in the Model class. How does Laravel call performInsert() in the example like this User::insert($data)

I have read in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/facades) about facades. But in the documentation it is written that class must extend with `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade` but the Model class doesn't extend with Facade also. Any help?

How is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DB::table('users')->insert()` this how you should call the function.

You are not giving it the model .

see [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#inserts)

Comment: It is working already... Without static keyword how are we writing DB::insert()

Comment: @AliMehdi I checked the docuemntation and modified my answer check it.

Comment: Thanks... I am actually working with models.. When model is called it is like User::insert().. Right? That model takes same query builder on back end. How

Comment: Inside Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, there is no function named insert()

Comment: where you are and exactly what you are asking, I am unable to understand still now :(

Comment: There is a function named performInsert()

Comment: @AliMehdi I got the method, but what is your question now ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102581/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-ali-mehdi).